# On grayed out answers, the comments section highlights instantaneously as opposed to fading in with the rest of the question

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I don't recall this being a thing before, since it'd quite annoying and visually jarring, but I've observed this recently.

- Look at a downvoted answer with comments
- Mouse over the comments section
- Observe that the comments appear immediately whereas the rest of the answer fades in

Note that it doesn't matter if you mouse over comments or the answer first, the behavior is present in both cases.

What I expect to see:

- The comments section and the answer fade in at an equal cadence.

I've only observed this on Meta <s>so I'm not sure if this happens on Stack Overflow *too*</s>, and there are reports of this happening network-wide.

For added annoyingness, if one has the fixed top-bar enabled *and* is hovering over a grayed out question, the top bar flickers for a bit and reappears.

Comment: Funny, I saw exactly that earlier, but thought it was just always like that and I hadn't noticed yet. It happens also when clicking the "show all comments" link.

Comment: It happens on the main site too. [Repro here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50228904/7832176) (may get deleted soon).

Comment: @KeyurPotdar It's still reproducible on that now deleted answer (10k+).

Comment: I just saw it over on RPG as well, so it looks like it's a network-wide issue.  Definitely don't remember seeing it before today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As Scoots noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367478/on-grayed-out-answers-the-comments-section-highlights-instantaneously-as-oppose/367877#367877), the problem here is that there are two separate rules trying to apply a `transition` property to the `comment-text` class. Since only one of them can win, you get slowly-fading comment highlights but no fades for the hover-opacity on downvoted answer comments.

I introduced this with a fix for [Comment flag popup is hidden when flag from the negative voted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284084/comment-flag-popup-is-hidden-when-flag-from-the-negative-voted-answers/309970#309970) - I noticed the lack of a transition at the time, but honestly did not care because I don't usually spend a lot of time moving my mouse in and out of downvoted answers, and the previous behavior - a faded or obscured flagging dialog - seemed a lot worse.

But since there've been *two* bug reports on this now, I guess it's distracting for some people. I've proposed a fix that'll switch the opacity fade to the `comment-body` class, since Scoots' proposed solution requires two separate sets of rules to have intimate knowledge of each other and just feels like asking for trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Little late to the party, but there was originally support for this, the CSS transition property is being overridden by another in a higher priority rule:

[image]

Altering the overriding transition property to `transition: background-color linear 2s, opacity 0.5s;` would restore this functionality.